# addEventListener after fetched data

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom, callback

This is working code, but I want to simplify, correct, and improve the code.

```
window.addEvent = function(elem,type,callback) {
    var evt = function(e) {
        return callback.call(elem,e);
    };
    var cb = function(e) { return evt(e); };
    elem.addEventListener(type,cb,false);
    return elem;
};
window.findParent = function(child,filter,root) {
    do {
        if( filter(child)) return child;
        if( root && child == root) return false;
    } while(child = child.parentNode);
    return false;
};
function on(type, target, callback) {
  window.addEvent(document.body, type, function(e) {
    var s = window.findParent(e.srcElement || e.target, function(elm) {
        return elm.classList.contains(target);
    },this);

    if( s && callback ) {
        callback(e)
    }
  });
}
on("click", "page-link", function(e){
 console.log("hey its working");
});
```

In this example, I update the pagination with fetch, and I have to bind addEventlistener to every page link. I am thinking about, If its there a cleaner way, using the latest techniques?  (with pure Javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Response to statement

> In this example, I update the pagination with fetch, and I have to bind addEventlistener to every page link.

Actually, in the example code it appears that [`elem.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is called on `document.body`, not each link.

#### Variable Names

Some of the names are a bit misleading. For example `target` is used to check the class name of elements. Therefore a better name might be `targetClass`, `target_class`, etc. Similarly, `s` isn't very descriptive.

### Feedback

#### Traversing DOM

Let's look at the `findParent()` function:

> ```
> window.findParent = function(child,filter,root) {
>     do {
>          if( filter(child)) return child;
>          if( root && child == root) return false;
>      } while(child = child.parentNode);
>      return false;
> };
> ```

When would `root` ever evaluate to a `false`-y value? In the code above, `document.body` is passed, so that seems unlikely.

It might be simpler to use a `while` loop. Typically DOM traversing code I have seen would assign the child argument to a temporary variable (e.g. `currentNode`) and assign the parent node to that variable until the target node is found or the root is reached.

```
window.findParent = function(child,filter,root) {
    var currentNode = child;
    while(root != currentNode) {
        if (filter(currentNode )) {
            return currentNode ;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This could also be re-written as a `for` loop:

```
window.findParent = function(child,filter,root) {
    for(var currentNode = child; root != currentNode; currentNode = curentNode.parentNode) {
        if (filter(currentNode )) {
            return currentNode ;
        }
    }
return false;
```

#### Over-complicated `addEvent`

The addEvent function creates two functions (i.e. `evt` and `cb`) which basically just call `callback` passing the event object to the callback. These steps are superfluous. It could simply add the event listener, passing `cb` to the [`listener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) parameter:

```
window.addEvent = function(elem,type,callback) {
    elem.addEventListener(type,callback,false);
    return elem;
};
```

And does it need to return `elem`? That would support chaining but your example code doesn't assign that return value to anything or have a subsequent call...

### Simplification

This looks like a great application for an event delegate, unless there is some requirement I am missing about splitting out the functionality into those separate functions? See the example below, which adds the event handler to the root and then only calls the callback if the target of the event passes the filter.

```js
function on(eventType, targetClass, callback) {
  document.body.addEventListener(eventType, function (event) {
     if (event.target.classList.contains(targetClass)) {
       callback(event);
     }
  });
}

on("click", "page-link", function(e){
 console.log("hey its working", e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<h1>Header Text</h1>
  <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">3</a>
```

Comment: this simplification made my day, there was no reason to split the code into multiple functions, I think it was easy to write. Thank you for the well explained answer, now I understand better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `querySelectorAll()` - for example:

```
function on (type, target, callback) {
  document.querySelectorAll(target).forEach(function (elem) {
     elem.addEventListener(type, callback);
  })
}
```

Your function `findParent` seems similar to [`element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) . In case you need it to work with IE, you can use the code below. It works with a selector, not just a class name.

```
closest = (element, selector) => {
    while(element) {
        //For IE11
        if (!element.matches)
            element.matches = element.msMatchesSelector;

        if (element.matches(selector))
            return element;

        element = element.parentElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: with the sample usage of `on()`, `document.querySelectorAll()` would likely return no results when passed `"page-link"` unless there were elements with that tag name...

Comment: @SamOnela because in your `findParent` you find element using classList. You can change to `".page-link"`. Just my opinion, because pass and work with selector is better and flexible than just only 1 class.

Comment: I am just saying that the OP would have to change the original sample code... or to use the code you suggested, would have to alter it to something like: `document.querySelectorAll("." + target)`